A question of control of flyback converters
Considering control of flyback converters, is it possible to control a converter which has pure current load (configuration on the picture)? Does it have to always be purely resistive load, because I've never seen anything other than resistive loads.

(Image was drawn by me.)
This is itself oscillatory (without control), and when I state-space average, linearize and set my PID gains such that system becomes aperiodic and damped, it seems that in reality, it's oscillatory.
Edit: I'm trying to control output voltage.

Please edit the question and make it clear what quantity you control on the output. Voltage? And then, the current load is just an offset term. What you’re really controlling is the ripple waveform on the storage capacitor. The control can be hysteretic and unconditionally stable. Try building one :)

It's totally possible to control a flyback with a pure current load. One trick you can use is to employ current-mode control, rather than voltage-mode (PWM duty cycle) control.
You could, for example, use a fixed-off-time peak-current scheme: Whenever the primary current hits a certain maximum value, you turn the transistor off for a fixed amount of time. Then you turn it back on and repeat. You can then use the output of your PID controller as the maximum-current set-point.
The advantage of this is that the overall system becomes a first-order integrator: You're pushing a current (determined by the PID controller output) into the output bulk capacitor, causing the output voltage to slew up and down. Controlling such a system is really simple since you've got an overall phase shift of 90°. Even pure proportional feedback (just the P in PID) will do the trick.
Here's a simulation of a silly little discrete boost converter that uses pure proportional feedback with peak-current mode control:

As you can see, it's rock-solid with a pure current load attached to it (discounting the feedback resistors). It's actually even somewhat overdamped.
In this circuit, R1 serves as the current sensing shunt. A variable offset voltage is added to it via R10 by means of a current produced by the error amplifier Q4/Q5, and this shifted signal is fed into a NE555 timer. The effect of this is that the 555 will switch Q1 off once the current through it exceeds a certain maximum, and this maximum is influenced by the error amplifier (the higher the collector current of Q5, the lower the trip point). Finally, C1/R15/D4 cause the 555 to switch Q1 back on after a fixed amount of time.
Most modern boost / flyback controller ICs operate on this principle. (Note that the flyback is an isolated derivative of the boost topology - both behave identically from a control perspective.)

Other than current mode control, can I use voltage mode control in this situation?

@usernamenenad Given that you'd have two poles at f=0, I'm not sure how you could possibly stabilize this while keeping DC voltage regulation, unfortunately... Current-mode control is rather unique in that it removes one pole entirely. A resistive load shifts those poles towards higher frequencies, making it possible to stabilize the system with non-zero feedback at DC.
